# filter only readable characters from a large txt file

Tags: java, regex

I have a large .txt file with full of readable and unreadable characters. I am trying to create a Java program that can create a new .txt file with only readable characters from the previous .txt file. Please help me to do this. Any code would be much appreciated. I am new to Java.

Comment: What counts as "unreadable"? What's the encoding of the file?

Comment: So it isn't a text file. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by readable u mean all characters from 'a' until 'z' and from '1' until '9'
then you could filter those out with a regex like so:

```
public static String removeSpecialCharacters(String sentence) {
    //StringBuilder container to store all the data in
    StringBuilder stringB = new StringBuilder();
    //loop trough all the characters from the sentence
    for (char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
        //only store characters that are equal to the below values
        if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == ' ' ) {
            stringB.append(c);
        }
    }
    return stringB.toString().toLowerCase();
}
```

You can use the return type (String) to append into the new .txt container. Lets say, for each line you read from the old file loop trough the removeSpecialCharacters() method and use the return value and append it into the new .txt file.

If we read the [standard java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) on read/write files we can compile the following code:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        readFromFile();

    }

    private static void writeToFile(String line) {
        // Convert the string to a
        // byte array.
        byte data[] = removeSpecialCharacters(line).getBytes();
        Path p = Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/outFile.txt");

        try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(p, CREATE, APPEND))) {
            out.write(data, 0, data.length);
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }    
    }

    private static void readFromFile() {
        Path file = Paths.get("/home/user/Desktop/inFile.txt");
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writeToFile(line +"\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }

    public static String removeSpecialCharacters(String sentence) {
        //StringBuilder container to store all the data in
        StringBuilder stringB = new StringBuilder();
        //loop trough all the characters from the sentence
        for (char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
            //only store characters that are equal to the below values
            if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == ' ' ) {
                stringB.append(c);
            }
        }
        return stringB.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes the file is UTF-8. This solution works for this set of characters.  It may perform poorly under very specific circumstances if any multi-byte characters (code points >= 128) are required... If the file contains invalid byte sequences eg: hex `C2 30`.  I am being picky of course.

Comment: how can i include special characters also into this code? sorry for basic questions!!

Comment: @chirathdealwis extend the ` if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == ' ' )` with  ` || c == '%'` or another special character if you want.